# Excel VBA Autofill across columns

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

I want to edit the range in Autofill code below but I'm not sure how.

```
'find last used cell in the row to the right
Range("B59").End(xlToRight).Select

'auto fill the formula for "Total TV"
ActiveCell.AutoFill Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1))
```

At present, the code finds the last valid cell in a row, then it autofills one cell to the right.

What I want to do:

I would to find the last valid cell, then select the active cell and the cells from 3 rows below it too and then autofill one cell to the right.

In pictures it would look like this:

1. find last valid cell in row 59:

[image]

2. select active cell and cells 3 rows below:

[image]

3. Autofill one cell to the right

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. No need to Select

```
Sub x()

Dim r As RANGE

Set r = RANGE("B59").End(xlToRight)
r.Resize(4).AutoFill r.Resize(4, 2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! just what i wanted.